# Achieve looping a user input form and consolidate the output into another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a user input interface in Excel that looks like this:

[image]

Where cell B1, B2 are user input cells; A4 and below are also user input cells, but the number of rows is not limited, so the user can enter 3 accounts as shown in screenshot example, or more than that;

I am looking to add a Macro where when the user clicks Submit, the results are consolidated into another worksheet with a format like this:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsqgC.png)]

The display of the data entered under Account is broken down into different rows, while the first and last name entry is multiplied;

With VBA, I am able to achieve the basic function of submitting with one entry of data under Account, using this:

```
Private Sub data_input() 

ws_output = "Sheet2" 
next_row = Sheets(ws_output).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row 
Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 1).Value = Range("FN").Value
Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 2).Value = Range("LN").Value 
Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 3).Value = Range("A_1").Value 

End Sub
```

(The FN, LN, A_1 are the names I assigned to the user input cells)

However unless I copy and paste the Sheets(ws_output).Cells(next_row, 1) lines multiple times, it does not achieve for multiple entries of data under Account, nor does it detect by itself how many rows of data the user enters under Account;

What would be some of the ways to tweet the VBA code to achieve this;

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub data_input()
    Dim ws_output As String
    Dim sht_out As Worksheet, c As Range
    Dim ws_in As String, lastRow As Long
    ws_in = "Sheet1"
    ws_output = "Sheet2"
    Set sht_out = Sheets(ws_output)
    ' Locate the first blank cell in Col A on sht_out
    Set c = sht_out.Cells(sht_out.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    ' Last row of user input
    lastRow = Sheets(ws_in).Cells(Sheets(ws_in).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow > 3 Then
        With c.Resize(lastRow - 3, 1)
            ' Populate data on sht_out
            .Value = Range("FN").Value
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("LN").Value
            .Offset(0, 2).Value = Sheets(ws_in).Range("A4:A" & lastRow).Value
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Offset property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.Resize property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Hello, thanks so much for the input! I do see this VBA working, I'm just trying to understand one part of the code in order to modify it a bit to fit the specific use case. What does the If statement and With statement perform, and any specific implications in terms of setting the lastRow to be > 3?

Comment: lastRow = 3 means there is not any account input from users. `With` statement an make your code easier to read and also improve the performance of your code in some cases. _Microsoft documentation:_

> [With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)